# CALayer has no AccessibilityIdentifier

Tags: xcode, calayer, ui-automation, xcuitest

I have built a proof of concept that creates a CAShapeLayer object and I am able to set it's AccessibilityLabel correctly.  However, I am unable to set an AccessibilityIdentifier (it seems this property exists for UIView objects, but not for CALayer objects?).

Does anyone know how to access it for CALayer objects - or if it is even possible?

Comment: That is correct. It exists for views but not layers. Your later will have to be in a view though. So set it on the view.

Comment: @Fogmeister - I have multiple layer objects within a single 'content' uiview. So that won't work. Any other way round this?

Comment: I haven't tried it in practice, but you could adopt `UIAccessibilityIdentification` protocol and implement `accessibilityIdentifier` if you have subclassed the `CALayer` or even adopt the protocol in an extension of `CALayer` and return its `name` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alladinian's suggestion above worked perfectly:

"I haven't tried it in practice, but you could adopt UIAccessibilityIdentification protocol and implement accessibilityIdentifier if you have subclassed the CALayer or even adopt the protocol in an extension of CALayer and return its name for example."

Answer (score 0):

```
class AccessibilityLayer: CALayer, UIAccessibilityIdentification {
    var accessibilityIdentifier: String?
}
let layer = AccessibilityLayer()
layer.accessibilityIdentifier = "MyAccessibilityID"
```

Something like this?